# Set up JDK error....in android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

i was just working in my code and all of a sudden my android studio shows underlining all over the program. i am not able to guess what is the error

things i tried:-
Restating
rebooting
creating alternate project
reinstalling android studio

but the error seems inconvincable but one thing i noticed is that the red underline seems to only come for java files and not xml files

[Please click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehqo3.png)

to add more information.. basic things like imageview content menu item inflater are going red

Comment: What did you do right before the errors appeared? What error messages do you receive? You can't expect anyone to solve the problem by just stating that "it's red in some places, help".

Comment: i was just add an extra activity and all of a sudden every line of my java code went red.(you cant blame the code because i reinstalled android studio)

Comment: Well, that answer doesn't cut it. Adding an extra activity in AS doesn't crash the program normally. There must be something else you did. Also, you still haven't provided anything regarding what the actual errors say. Red underlinings can't be derived to one problem, and one problem only. You should understand this.

Comment: there are red underlines only in all java files with one basic error cannot find class so and so and inside the class cannot resolve the items for all basic thing like image view inflator contents @Mumfi

Comment: I can't help you. Copy the exact error message and search for it on Stack Overflow. You are sure to find other people that have had the exact same error message.

Comment: @Mumfi when i do alt+enter near the red underline it says setup JDK what does that mean

Answer (score 0):

Is red lines displaying in all of your activities if yes then then there is some error in one of your projects xml file. Find it out. Check messages in android studio. let know if you cant figure it out

Comment: there are red underlines only in all java files with one basic error cannot find class so and so and inside the class cannot resolve the items for all basic thing like image view inflator content

Comment: when i do alt+enter near the red underline it says setup JDK what does that mean

Comment: @Anirudh I'm facing same issue ("Setup JDK" option only and no other option to fix). Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Build > Clean Project` or `Gradle > Refresh all projects`

Answer (score 0):

there is something called -

packagename.R ex: com.example.R .

Check for this in **imports of .java file** there should be this line like

import com.example.R

, if its there  then this is because there is error in your xml file in values or menu or layout probably on some id.

If jdk is issue then

1. if Ubuntu - do - > sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -here first check what version of java you have
2. if its is windows setup your jdk/jre in environment variables to java 8

   For these two steps you will get lot of links from google.

   if still it is not resolved last option then try redo the last step due to which this error has occurred.

Try creating another android project and see your getting same errors in java file, if no then its not jdk issue this is something has to do with you project R file as there is some error in your xml files. Try to clean/re-build project.

Post your code if possible

NOTE YOUR PROBLEM LIES ONLY IN THIS SCOPE. THERE CANNOT BE ANY OTHER REASONS.